# how to visualize sample space in exercises like "roll 3 6-sided dice, and find probability that sum is $\geq$, $\leq$, or $x$?

Tags: probability-theory, dice

if I have three 6-sided dice, and I need to find probability that sum is $x$, $\leq$, or $\geq x$, under these conditions I need to sketch sample space in order to find events I'm interested in. This would be simple if I'd have to roll two 6-sided dice, because I simply have to write each number of the first die vertically and each number of the second die horizontally (to visualize it, think of microsoft excel in which you draw a table with rows, and columns), and this is the best way to visualize sample space. But here's the problem: what if I have 3 dice? it would be tedious to write each event without creating a table, because I'd have more than two dice. Where should I put the third die? I was wondering if there's a way to visualize these kind of problems easily.

Comment: The table might be long, but it’ll work: Put all the 36 duplets obtained from the first two dice horizontally, and the numbers from the third dice vertically.

Comment: are first two dice parallel? or you mean putting them all in one row?

Comment: Why limit yourself to a 2-D representation? Think of the sample space as the lattice of points $(x,y,z)$ with integer coordinates each in the range $1-6$. Then the event of having a sum of $k$ is the set of these points on the plane $x+y+z=k$. Having a sum $\leq k$ is the set of lattice points on or below this plane, and having a sum $\geq k$ is the set of lattice points on or above this plane. Note these planes are all parallel, and are perpendicular to the line $x=y=z$.

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini Like, the horizontal axis contains things like (1,1),(1,2),(2,1)(3,1),(1,3),(2,2),(4,6),(6,6) etc. and the vertical axis contains 1,2,3,4,5,6. So the intersection of, say, (1,2) with 3 gives (1,2,3) and the intersection of (2,1) with 2 gives (2,1,2) etc.

Comment: You say "I have to sketch the sample space." Is this a requirement of the problem? Because you don't necessarily need to sketch the sample space to find probabilities of various sums.

Comment: @paw88789 I need to see every possibilities in order to find number of events I'm interested in. for example, sum <= 5, I need to find every (x,y,z) that have a sum <= 5

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini you can just list these tuples: $(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(1,3,1),(2,1,1),(2,1,2),(2,2,1),(3,1,1)$ (if you read these as 3-digit numbers, they're in ascending order, which may give you some insight into how I came up with the list). A 216-cell table is not much use if it is only 10 entries that you're interested in. For instance, you know that you'll never need the 6 column because getting a single 6 on any die is disqualifying (too large). Same even for 5s and 4s. So you could also try a 3x3x3 table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method: You could do something like this: Start with a table of two dice sums:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc} + & 1&2&3&4&5&6 \\ \hline 
1&2&3&4&5&6&7 \\
2&3&4&5&6&7&8 \\
3&4&5&6&7&8&9 \\
4&5&6&7&8&9&10 \\
5&6&7&8&9&10&11 \\
6&7&8&9&10&11&12
\end{array}$$

Then for any $k$ with $3\le k \le 18$, you could look at this table and determine how many ways you could get $k$ from a table entry with one more die roll.

For instance if $k=9$, any entry in the table from $3$ to $8$ could get to a sum of $9$ with the roll of a third die. There are $25$ entries in this table in that range. So there are $25$ ways to roll three dice to a sum of $9$.

Another method: Make six tables, each six by six (so each table represents rolling two of the three dice). Each table is associated with a die roll ($1, 2, 3, 4, 5,$ or  $6$). Then at each entry of a given table, add the two table indices plus the associated third roll.

For instance the table where the third roll is $4$ would look like this.
$${\rm Third\; roll\; is\;} 4 \hspace{.2in}  \begin{array}{c|cccccc} 4+ & 1&2&3&4&5&6 \\ \hline 
1&6&7&8&9&10&11 \\
2&7&8&9&10&11&12 \\
3&8&9&10&11&12&13\\
4&9&10&11&12&13&14 \\
5&10&11&12&13&14&15 \\
6&11&12&13&14&15&16
\end{array}$$
The six tables constructed in this way would give you a diagram of the full sample space.